# Can you use/interchange the same Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 sd-card in a Raspberry Pi 4 and a Raspberry Pi 5?

Tags: raspberrypi, sd-card, 23.10

I have both a Raspberry Pi 4 and a Raspberry Pi 5, and I am wondering if it is safe and successful to use a Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 formatted SD-Card between the two (ie. use it in the rpi4 for a while, power it off, use it in the rpi5 for a while, power it off, use it in the rpi4 for a while, etc.).

So far I've  been using different sd cards between them.

Comment: It will most likely work. But even if it works, you may end up having inconsistencies in some logs and other files on your SD-card (created while Ubuntu is running), since the two boards have hardware differences. This could make it harder to decipher those logs in case something goes wrong.

So maybe it's OK to use the same SD-card with both boards interchangeably, just for quick tests with a fresh installation, but not in any long time setup. If you have some additional software operating GPIOs, etc., then you need to be extra-careful and double check the schematics of both boards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested with an SD card I've been using Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 on a Raspberry Pi 5 on, and put it in a Raspberry Pi 400 and had no issues.